I need to prevent a small quantity of water from freezing using a solid state controller circuit
I am currently using a 10W resistive heater element powered by a 5V 2A DC power supply, which works fine, but is unsatisfactory since it's either on (plugged in) or off (unplugged) making it subject to human frailty (sometimes I forget to plug it in as the temperature drops and the water freezes, or I forget to unplug it as the temperature warms up, and the water gets hot(both are bad outcomes for my project)
That said, I'd like to add an ambient temperature sensing device that begins feeding current at or near 0C and gradually increases current until max current is applied to the element at or around -7C.
On hand, I have a broad selection of transistors(too many to list but can do on request), MF52D 200Ω-10KΩ NTC thermistors, 10KΩ trim pots, a broad selection of diodes, resistors, caps etc., and a hope that I can cobble together a circuit that will do the job.
The hope is to develop a prototype functional control circuit that would lend itself to limited production of a compact PCB build.
I'm hopeful that someone here will steer me in the right direction as I am operating on just enough knowledge to think that I can do something that may be impossible. TIA

if all you want is to prevent it from freezing, add antifreeze.

I wish, but the 'water' in my project is a water based solution which will be consumed... not something I can add antifreeze to, lol. But thanks for the idea... sometimes the solutions are that easy, right?

This is the sort of thing that is easily done with an Arduino Nano, an NTC thermistor and a few resistors, plus a MOSFET.  You could even add a display to show the reading/output with minimal work. Since an Arduino is little more than an MCU with a few support parts on a PCB, a bespoke PCB with SMT parts would be a simple step beyond that. I suggest time-proportioning the heating (aka PWM) to maximize efficiency.

Your “gradually increases current” is handicapping you here. A transistor dissipates 0W open-circuit and 0W shirt-circuit but a lot more in between: sometimes as much as the heating element itself. Use the thermal inertia of the heater to smooth the heating, and use duty cycle to control the smoothed amount. You may be able to make this happen naturally by placing the temperature sensor near the heater.

@SpehroPefhany thanks for your input.. In my case, I feel that although using a Nano or Zero would be a solution, it is overkill, and the bulk and expense would render the end product non marketable. (see details about the product in the comments to Luke Gary)

@MartinKochanski, thanks for your input. I appreciate your observation re my desire to gradually increase current, and now recognize that operating a MOSFET in its ohmic region is to be avoided. At the moment, I have not determined a way to sample the temperature of the liquid, only the ambient air temp.

This can be done pretty simply by using the NTC thermistor and a trim pot configured as a variable resistor to make a voltage divider connected to the gate of a mosfet. Essentially you will set the output of the divider to equal the Vgs threshold voltage of the N-Channel mosfet and when the temperature is below your desired temperature at the location of the NTC (when the NTC is grounded on one side), the mosfet will begin to conduct and pass current to your heating element until the voltage drops and pulls the gate to or below its threshold voltage. Its a simple thermostat really, and so long as you dont need to be very precise, the variability of the mosfet Vgs threshold voltage with ambient temperature shouldnt affect the setpoint much, but best to test and check datasheets.
BEWARE!
mount the MOSFET far from the heating element and connect the thermistor to the circuit via a cable to prevent the circuit from releasing the magic smoke!
Below is a simulation of this and modelling the mass that is being heated as a 1D lumped element. Adjust to fit your application.



Thanks for your input Luke.
I think I understand your advice, for starters, I that will need to choose a suitable mosfet to deliver the 2A current since most BJT's will just fry?? My lack of e-engineering knowledge shows up big time when I try to parse your schematic. Am I right in assuming that the picture is not intended to be specific to my needs, but rather an example for reference? As I look at it, I am mystified by the 3 separate circuits... do they connect in some way? It appears to be a ?screenshot? from a parametric circuit design? Sorry to be so slow on my understanding.

As I learn about Mosfets, if I understand correctly what I read, a mosfet is typically used as a switch, as opposed to a variable resistance(What I think I am looking for) I read that mosfets want to be turned on quickly to prevent heat build-up, so my question is now going to be about how the mosfet will perform if I desire a low current at, say, -1C? That said, would my needs be better served by using a power amplifier or Darlington? God, I feel so ignorant at this point.

Hey Bob, your understanding is along the right path. The reason to use a mosfet here is because the device transitions between two modes of operation when the voltage between the gate and the source increases. As the voltage increases, it will go from behaving like a variable resistance (linear or ohmic region) to saturating and acting more like a switch. They're nonlinear devices, so it essentially can provide more power to the heater when you're far away from your setpoint temperature. Its generally easier and cheaper to source an n channel mosfet for these types of tasks.

Thats a simulation in LTSpice, the upper left section is the circuit you would want to build, and honestly, so long as your mosfet is rated for the maximum current you wish to deliver through the resistive heater (calculate that with ohms law and just assume the mosfet resistance is zero), it should be fine to build and tweak with little fuss.

The three sections are connected in simulation with a few of the formulas. I am modelling the temperature dependence of the NTC resistor as well as a thermal mass that is coupled to the heater with some thermal resistance as a 1 dimensional chunk which isn't representative of reality, but close enough to get an idea of the approximate time needed to change the temperature of the mass. Not modelling any losses to the environment or anything more complex. First order approximation.

Thanks for your kind help and patience Luke. The circuit in your answer uses a separate source for the control (3.3v) and the load (11.2v) In my device, I only have the 5V supply. Is there a way to make that work?
So, full disclosure is maybe of some help. For years, I have been installing these 10W resistive heater elements into hummingbird feeders (they winter over in my area).. The nectar will freeze just when the little guys need the energy the most. Until now, as noted above, it has been up to the human to ensure it is plugged in when frost is expected, but unplugged when it warms.

I want to automate the device to respond to the ambient temp, hence this project. So, 1. accuracy IS NOT an issue 2. Cost IS an issue. 3. Weatherproof IS an issue. Therefore, simplicity demands a cheap power source (5V2A wallwart) and a PCB device that can be potted in epoxy. If the device needs a heatsink, that MAY be a challenge, but I think that can be overcome. When the mosfet is in its ohmic region, it will heat up, yes?

Can you please offer your opinion regarding using a Darlington Pair, say, a TIP102 for example, instead of a MOSFET?

Use a bimetallic thermostat in series with the resistor, and in good thermal contact with the resistor and container. You might try a refrigerator thermostat, such as this adjustable one or this fixed temperature device, or one of these, if it has normally open contacts for a defroster (references for purpose of illustration; not sure they'll work on your project).

Thanks DrMoishe, I have several reasons why I do not wish to use an electro-mechanical switch of any kind since these are on/off devices. I need an analog device that begins delivering low current at or near 0C and increases that current as the ambient temperature drops.
